# How to auto-start all screenlets in unity only(not Gnome-shell)?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, autostart, screenlets

I want to auto-start all screenlets in unity environment only as it also auto-start in Gnome-shell too (as it is not working well in gnome-shell), i,e, i want to only edit one file not all screenlet items files
[image: startup aaplications]
as i have a lot of sceenlets on my desktop
[image: My-Desktop]
And i know how to auto-start an application from this [site](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/make-applications-autostart-only-in.html).

Comment: What are you talking about.I know how to auto-start an application in a certain environment, but each screenlet item have an auto-start element so i want to control them all not every item alone.and i haven't tried any thing yet(because i don't know what to do, so i ask).

Comment: ☹ seem impossible ☹

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think its possible to edit just one file - you'll need to edit all the screenlet files - it seems all screenlets in the autostart folder are named `[something]Screenlet.desktop`

You could use a simple script such as this which would append `OnlyShowIn=Unity` to all screenlet files in the users autostart folder

To use, copy and paste the following into a file in your home folder called `hidescreenlets`

Then run the script using:

```
bash ~/hidescreenlets
```

If you add more screenlets, just rerun the script.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$HOME/.config/autostart"

if  [ ! -d  $dir ] ; then
  echo "cannot find $dir"
  exit
fi

cd $dir

files=`find -name "*Screenlet.desktop"`
for file in $files ; do
  srch=`grep -i "OnlyShowIn=Unity" $file`
  #echo $file "$srch"
  if [ "$srch" == "" ] ; then
     echo "OnlyShowIn=Unity" >> $file
     #echo $file "$srch"
  fi
done
```

---

**backing up**

If you are feeling nervous... either use Nautilus to backup the ~/.config/autostart folder to another folder or you can achieve the same via the following:

```
mkdir ~/backupscreenlets
cp ~/.config/autostart/* ~/backupscreenlets
```

Look at the contents of `~/backupscreenlets` - it will have the same files as `~/.config/autostart`

If you then want your original files:

```
cp ~/backupscreenlets/* ~/.config/autostart
```

Comment: Did you try it and works for you ???(i am afraid to make a mistake and make a failure in something)

Comment: yes I did - I've added a backup instruction if you are feeling nervous... and you are quite right not to run random stuff written on the internet :).  Follow the backup instruction - and you will be able to return to day 1 state anytime you want to.